# TODO in Play Framework 2.7.x

Tags: java, playframework

The [Javadocs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.3/api/java/play/mvc/Controller.html#TODO-play.mvc.Http.Request-) say `Http.Request` is expected but unsure what exactly the value to pass?

Before:

```
public class BookController extends Controller {

    public Result index() {
        return TODO; // Returns a nice TODO page
    }

}
```

Now (2.7.x):

```
public class BookController extends Controller {

    public Result index() {
        return TODO(<what to pass here>); // Http.Request req is saying cannot resolve symbol req
    }

}
```

Would like the pretty TODO page like before.

Comment: As per this [link](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/Migration27)

All Play’s error pages have been updated to render a CSP nonce if the CSPFilter is present. This means that **the error page templates must take a request as a parameter.** 
In 2.6.x, the TODO field was previously rendered as a static result instead of an action with an HTTP context.

For my project I had to put whole static html in index.scala.html :

`public static Result index(){   return ok(index.render());  }`

Comment: @Sri9911 That works. If you can put that up as answer, I'd be glad to upvote and accept.

Comment: Sure... Happy to help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this [link](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/Migration27) all Play’s error pages have been updated to render a CSP nonce if the CSPFilter is present. This means that the error page templates must take a request as a parameter. In 2.6.x, the TODO field was previously rendered as a static result instead of an action with an HTTP context. 
For my project I had to put whole static html in index.scala.html :

```
     public static Result index(){ 
         return ok(index.render()); 
}
```